# Melhor prática para fazer Mass Assignment

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Para obter as facilidades que o framework se propõe, no caso específico de se gravar dados numa tabela de um banco de dados, podemos utilizar o recurso do 'mass assignment', que significa, em tradução livre, 'inserção em massa (de dados)'.

Eu segui um tutorial, e entendi que, partindo-se de um princípio bastante simples, alcança-se o objetivo.

Meu cenário se constituía de um formulário (fonte dos dados a inserir), um método num 'controller', uma classe que herdava 'Model' e, claro, um banco de dados.

Mas, ao executar as rotinas, vi que o banco de dados aceitava a gravação, mas não preenchia as colunas. Isto é, o registro existia, mas tudo em branco.

Acredito que tenha descoberto o problema, mas gostaria de saber se a solução é a melhor indicada.

Primeiramente, era assim, enquanto havia problema de gravação em branco:

Nome da tabela no banco de dados: 'produtos'
Campos desta tabela: id, nome, descricao, valor, quantidade.
Formulário-fonte dos dados (retirei a 'gordura', deixando o
essencial):

```
<form action="{{action('controllerTeste@adiciona')}}" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{{csrf_token()}}}"/>
    <input name="namNome"/>
    <input name="namDescricao"/>
    <input name="namValor"/>
    <input name="namQuantidade" />
    <button type="submit">Salvar</button>
</form>
```

Para reforço do entendimento, acima, o campo com o atributo 'hidden' é necessário para que não haja impedimento à gravação na tabela.

O método que disparava a gravação:

```
public function adiciona(){
        $params = Request::all();
        $produto = new Produto ($params);
        $produto->save();
        return redirect()->action('controllerTeste@lista')->withInput();
    }//adiciona
```

A classe que herda 'model':

```
<?php
namespace tempo;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Produto extends Model
{
    protected  $table = "produtos";
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = array('nome','descricao','valor','quantidade');
}
?>
```

A partir do erro percebido, comecei a imaginar como o Laravel conseguiria saber, pelo que está escrito no controller, como associar cada dado que chegava do formulário para a coluna correta no banco de dados.

A variável $fillable, na classe Produto, era clara, mas a chegada dos dados vinha do controller, através da variável $params, que não dizia nada em relação a qual campo do formulário e em que ordem se relacionava com $fillable.

Foi neste ponto que 'desconfiei' dos nomes dos campos no formulário. Para minha conveniência de separar nome de atributos, todos os campos que pertencessem a 'name' começariam por 'nam' e todos os atributos 'id' teriam identificadores começando por 'id' da mesma forma.

Troquei, então, os nomes dos campos do formulário para coincidirem exatamente com o nome das colunas no banco de dados.

Aí tudo funcionou.

Em seguida, me perguntei, mas serei obrigado a pôr nomes em formulários sempre sob esta regra? Não haveria uma espécie de 'alias' para cada campo do formulário que pudesse ser traduzido para o nome das colunas da tabela-alvo?

Procurei na web e, após alguma pesquisa, encontrei um código  que funcionou.

Para aplicá-lo, retornei os nomes do formulário para minha maneira de escrevê-los tradicional, e reescrevi o método no controller para 'traduzir' os nomes desse formulário para os nomes das colunas da tabela-alvo.

O método do controller ficou assim:

```
 public function adiciona(){
    $produto = Produto::create(array(
      'nome' =>Request::input('namNome'),
      'descricao'  => Request::input('namDescricao'),
      'valor'   => Request::input('namValor'),
      'quantidade' => Request::input('namQuantidade')));
    $produto->save();
    return redirect()->action('controllerTeste@lista')->withInput();
}//adiciona
```

O que foi substituído na rotina do controller, foi substituir

```
$params = Request::all();
$produto = new Produto ($params);
```

por

```
$produto = Produto::create(array(
          'nome' =>Request::input('namNome'),
          'descricao'  => Request::input('namDescricao'),
          'valor'   => Request::input('namValor'),
          'quantidade' => Request::input('namQuantidade')));
```

Então, reitero o que está escrito no título desta pergunta: é a melhor prática?

Answer (score 1):

Não é necessário escrever tanto, faça o seguinte com o seu método adiciona:

```
public function adiciona(Request $request){
    //capturar todos os dados do form
    $dadosFormulario = $request->all();
    //fazer insert
    $produto = Produto::create($dadosFormulario);
    return redirect()->action('controllerTeste@lista')->withInput();
}
```

Na sua model você precisa declarar qual a sua chave primária, faça o seguinte:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'chave_primaria';
```

Comment: geekcom, fazendo do seu jeito eu iria cair no problema da 'tradução' entre os nomes dos campos no formulário e os nomes das colunas na tabela do banco dedados. Request->all() traria todos os campos, mas iria dar erro na hora de gravar no banco. Nâo é isto?

Comment: Daria erro caso a sua chave primária tenha algum nome diferente de 'id', que é usado por padrão no Eloquent, editei a resposta acima, creio que isso resolve.